# I Got a New T-shirt Today

Tags: discussion

Special thanks to Karsten for making this happen!

[image]

Comment: So cool! How did you get that shirt? Also you look like a combination of two actors.

Comment: @MelanieShebel - There was/is a thread [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5195/thanks-for-participating-in-the-election-and-contributing-to-the-site) and maybe one other. Basically I asked for one and he was generous enough to send two of them to me. And yes, I am frequently mistaken for Tom Cruise or Daniel Craig :)

Comment: Ooh, I like that one much more than the green ones Stack Exchange sent out after the beta ended. (On the other hand, it would be great to print up some stickers again for advertising...)

Comment: @GeoffHutchison - Not shown is the other t-shirt, it's black with the same graphic.