# What are your views on how Matter Modeling and Chemistry sites should interact?

Tags: discussion

This is a [question](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5186/72973) posted by Geoff Hutchison as part of the recent election. Martin suggested we discuss on Meta after the election is done. I reposted with slight edits; I will refrain from cross-posting it on Matter Modeling, but maybe someone could add some kind of appropriate link on their meta.

#### In light of some users posting questions on both sites, what are your views on how the sites should interact?

- Should there be certain types of questions migrated to Matter
  Modeling? (e.g., that seem to be a better fit.. like ones specific to
  a particular program)
- Should there be a "community specific" close to migrate to Matter Modeling?
- How would this be made clear to new users, who may not know of one or the other site, or why some questions may be better suited for one site or another?
- How do we minimize people posting questions in both places?

Comment: I've been quite happy with the way things have been going. One suggestion [I made](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/357/5) was to migrate things faster, by directly doing it rather than first asking whether or not it's ok.

Comment: Interesting question and I’m curious to see how it pans out as my work is in modeling. I tend to avoid Matter Modeling as, in its infancy, it has a conversational tone but I have hopes that as it grows that the chat-like nature of it mellows out. Looking forward to its growth and curious to see how this initiative works out!

Comment: @MelanieShebel - I also dislike some of the questions over there and pushed close votes and brought up things in meta, but at the moment, it's obvious that the current Mod team has different goals. (shrug)

Answer (score 7):

> Should there be certain types of questions migrated to Matter Modeling? (e.g., that seem to be a better fit.. like ones specific to a particular program)

Yes. Judging from my personal experience, there are quite a few questions that remain unrecognised here, or even badly received, that may well be a good fit there.

I usually go about and ask in their chat about these cases and post comments here. (I am doing that for other sites, too.) Occasionally I just send it over. I'm a member there, I have a bit of experience migrating now, oftentimes I can make the right call.

Apart from that, everybody can comment on these questions and raise custom flags.

> Should there be a "community specific" close to migrate to Matter Modeling?

No. These are still pretty few occasions which can easily be handled manually. We don't need to crowd our already crowded queue. Most of these cases would probably have to be expedited anyway.

Apart from that, I don't want to deal with the formal change request.

Furthermore, if we open up this line, we need to discuss other sites, too. And from my point of view there is no evidence for having these either.

> How would this be made clear to new users, who may not know of one or the other site, or why some questions may be better suited for one site or another?

Following the above outlined workflow, you'll get a sense of the user and how they will further interact with our site or our partners.

In most cases where I asked about migration, the users were very forthcoming and thankful. It's easy to miss our partner site as they are still quite new.

It's probably for this reason alone that I would want to handle these cases manually. It gives the whole thing a more personal touch.

> How do we minimize people posting questions in both places?

If you follow the above and adding a note that cross-posting is discouraged, you've probably done as much as you can do.

My general experience is that cross-posting isn't a big problem for our site. Nevertheless it should still be discouraged.
I'm generally adding a note on both (all) posts with links to the other site(s). I'll then usually close the post at our end.
I'll tell them to delete the other posts and custom flag for this one to be reopened, or do the same for the other site.

If it's on matter modelling, there's a good chance it fits well there and poorly here, so it remains open there and closed here. If it doesn't get deleted by the cleanup procedures, this could be expedited, too.

Comment: I appreciate the comments from the Mod team. I brought up the "community specific" request because it seemed the right choice in voting a few times. But if it's a pain for the change request, the current system certainly works.

Comment: @Geoff I would like to clarify that I'm speaking for myself and not for the mod team, although I get what you mean. And if is obvious that my role as a moderator has influenced my view. A lot. I'm not sure how much of a pain the change request actually is; there was a time where Manish and jonsca discussed migration paths to other sites and we concluded to not go ahead. Obviously that is much longer ago and times change. From this I only remember that we should be able to support that it will be used, but not abused.

Comment: And there was another point which I now remembered. You can (or could) only choose graduated sites, which matter modelling is not yet. But since they changed those requirements some time ago, I'm not sure where we are at now.

Answer (score 6):

I feel like I should briefly give my thoughts since I brought it up a few times.

> Should there be certain types of questions migrated to Matter Modeling? (e.g., that seem to be a better fit.. like ones specific to a particular program)

Yes. I think now that Matter Modeling exists, questions specific to a particular program seem like a better fit.

As Martin mentioned in [his answer](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5226/5017) there are definitely some questions posted here that aren't getting enough attention and might do better over there.

I suspect as time goes on, the audience for Matter Modeling will be more clearly defined.

> Should there be a "community specific" close to migrate to Matter Modeling?

I mentioned this because it seems like the right choice in some Close votes. I welcome feedback from the Mod team because ultimately they perform the migration. Certainly if getting SE to make a formal change to the choices is painful, the current system works okay.

If raising a custom flag is a better option, I'll be happy to do that.

Comment: A custom flag would certainly help me, showing that at least one person familiar with both sites thinks that migration makes sense.

Comment: It's usually straighforward to recognize questions that are a better fit on matter modeling. Some are ambiguously so, but then it's usually better to explain the available choices to the OP and obtain their input. If a comp chem question doesn't get much attention here and it has no overt flaws then it is usually a good sign that it needs another audience.

Comment: I don't remember ever going over to mm to ask about migration, but for future ref, what would be the right chatroom for this request?

Comment: @Buck I usually go here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107323/modeling-matters most of the times Tyberius responds, so I guess we can keep it in house now. ;)

Comment: I think the custom flag makes sense because: (1) only moderators can perform migrations, and (2) flags directly bring the post to the moderators' attention, whereas closure doesn't -- you have to hope that they see it and read your close reason.

Comment: +1 for migration. I agree. PS. The existence of the matter modeling sub makes me want to do research in this area again. It's exciting stuff!